# Catalog Item of the Storefront catalog Configuration cannot be found

Tags: sxa-storefront

I am using Sitecore XC 9.0.3 with SXA.

On my SXA site I;

- added a Catalog Item Container component,
- assigned a product from the catalog (with item path `/sitecore/content/New tenant/test/Home/Catalogs/TestCatalog/Product`)
- added Product Information component
- saved

After saving I get the following error:

```
Error while rendering the view [Product Information] (item reference: [d09ebd2d-30f4-48b8-b7ab-0d6fce8c6c7b]) Please, make sure the rendering is configured properly or contact your administrator.
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): An unhandled exception occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Catalog Item of the Storefront catalog Configuration cannot be found.
at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Models.CommerceStorefront.get_CatalogItem()
at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Models.CommerceStorefront.get_Catalog()
at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Connect.Entities.ProductEntity.Initialize(CommerceStorefront storefront, Item item, List`1 variantEntityList)
at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Feature.Catalog.Repositories.BaseCatalogRepository.GetCatalogItemRenderingModel(IVisitorContext visitorContext, Item productItem)
at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Feature.Catalog.Repositories.BaseCatalogRepository.GetProduct(IVisitorContext visitorContext)
at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Feature.Catalog.Controllers.CatalogController.ProductInformation()
```

I confirmed that `DataProvider.config` as mentioned [here](https://blog.ryanbailey.co.nz/2018/06/sitecore-experience-commerce-catalog.html) is enabled.

I have a catalog selected at the following path: `/sitecore/content/New tenant/test/Home/Catalogs` (I guess otherwise it wouldn't be even possible to assign a product to the Catalog Item Container component).

I traced the error back to the following piece of code in the `Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Models.CommerceStoreFront` class:

```
public virtual Item CatalogItem
    {
      get
      {
        Field field = this.SiteCatalogConfiguration?.Fields[Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Constants.DataTemplates.SiteCatalogConfiguration.Fields.Catalog];
        if (field == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.Value))
          field = this.CatalogConfiguration.Fields[Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Constants.DataTemplates.CatalogConfiguration.Fields.Catalog];
        ID result;
        if (!ID.TryParse((object) field, out result))
          throw new InvalidItemException("Invalid catalog Id");
        Item obj = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(result);
        Assert.IsNotNull((object) obj, "Catalog Item of the Storefront catalog Configuration cannot be found.");
        return obj;
      }
    }
```

Apparently the `field` in above code snippet is correctly retrieved, but the related item cannot be found.

What configuration step am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by selecting the proper catalog under:

```
/sitecore/content/New tenant/test/Settings/Commerce/Catalog Configuration
```

It seemed to be put at a, in my installation, non-existing Habitat Catalog value.